# Changing from Metadata to Folders - files not appearing in library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, folder

I've been requested to remove the Metadata that was configured for a meeting site's document library.

It was structured around Year and Month metadata tags.

There was a big issue with being unable to have a file hold the same name, causing lots of issues uploading and unexpected overwriting and bad re-naming. The decision was made to remove metadata and use a single-level folder structure.

I added some folders, moved the files and everything worked fine, except that it was still filtering and viewing via the now redundent metadata tags. It looked like this:
[image: Metadata not yet removed]

Then I went into the Columns in the document library settings, and removed the Month and Year. Now, however, I'm faced with an empty library. It says: "There are no items to show in this view of the "Document Library" document library. To add a new item, click "New" or "Upload"."

Uploading files fails (file not found).
[image: No files!]

I was worried everything was lost (I did back it up), but turns out it is not. I can view the files in the explorer view, and the matadata has been stripped as I expected. Everything seems fine.
[image: Fine! Right?]

I've tried creating new views, and using the default "All Documents view" but whatever I do I can't seem to get these files to display in the document Library... It knows they are there because when I go into views, or column settings I can see them. I can also link them, and use them using their path.
[image]

Can anyone help?

**EDIT** I've added the "tree view" from the site settings menu, and this allows me to select the "Document Library" from "Site Content". This gives me what I'm expecting! A list with all the folders and files, however when I link to the library or select it under "Document Library" it's still as it was before.

I've noticed the URL end changes this:

..../MonthlyManagementReview/Document%20Library/Forms/Date%20View.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FMyESS%2FMonthlyManagementReview%2FDocument%20Library&

Instead of this:

.../MonthlyManagementReview/Document%20Library/Forms/Date%20View.aspx

[image: What I want!]

Comment: Is there any filtering on the view?

Comment: In the filtering section, it's on "Show all items in this view", so I don't think so.

Comment: A note on the URL change, SharePoint adds the RootFolder parameter.  It determines the folder that is opened in the library.

Comment: Yeah, it seems when I open a folder directly it behaves how I'd expect, showing files and sub-folders. However the default link/location to the library doesn't seem to point to the right place or something.